Trying to write a function that if product exists, then specific category cannot be deleted
I'm working on an ecommerce project in Laravel 10.48.8, my PHP version is 8.2.12.
I have used one to many relation to link the parent table categories to one of the child table products using foreign key in delete cascade.
I've used resource controller for categories to define a CRUD operation.
Issue: In the destroy function, I'm trying to establish that if a product exists in that specific category, then the category can not be deleted. However, it won't let me delete other categories as well that do not contain any products. Following is the function that I have written:
P.S. 'category_id' is a column in my products table, which is the foreign key used to link the primary key in the category table.
public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        $category=Category::findOrFail($id);
        $product = Product::with('category')->first();
        if(!$product->category_id)
        {
            if(File::exists($category->image))
            {
                File::delete($category->image);
            }
            $category->delete();
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('message','Cannot delete Categories with existing products!');
        }

    }


Have you tried changing $product->category_id with $product['category_id']

@Tayyab Hello, thank you for your comment and help. I have tried that, but unfortunately it gave me the same result.

I just saw you are getting first product from table which isn't right. Don't you have products relation in Category model? If yes then you can simply add check    if(count($category['products']) > 0) and skip getting Product.

You need to modify it like that:
public function destroy(string $id)
{
    $category=Category::findOrFail($id);
    if(count($category['products'] == 0))
    {
        if(File::exists($category->image))
        {
            File::delete($category->image);
        }
        $category->delete();
        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('message','Cannot delete Categories with existing products!');
    }

}

OR you can do it like this if you want to involve Products model with that:
public function destroy(string $id)
{
    $category=Category::findOrFail($id);
    $product = Product::where('category_id', $category['id'])->first();
    if(!$product)
    {
        if(File::exists($category->image))
        {
            File::delete($category->image);
        }
        $category->delete();
        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('message','Cannot delete Categories with existing products!');
    }

}


I tried the second way and it worked! Thank you!

Your Category model should have relation of categories look like below.
class Category extends Model
{

     public function products()
     {
          return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
     }
}

and then your destroy function should look like this to achieve what you want by using above relation.
    public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        $category=Category::findOrFail($id);
        if($category->products()->isNotEmpty())
        {
            if(File::exists($category->image))
            {
                File::delete($category->image);
            }
            $category->delete();
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('success','Category deleted successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('message','Cannot delete Categories with existing products!');
        }

    }


You don't need to fetch products in this function.
